# CakePHP custom helper works locally but not on server

Tags: cakephp, naming-conventions, helper

locally all is well.
but when i moved my app to my server i got an error because cake didn't recognize my custom helper.

the error for my helper 'Halp' was

```
    Undefined property: View::$Halp
```

it is declared inside of my app_controller.php file like:

```
    var $helpers = array('Time','Halp','FileUpload.FileUpload','Html','Ajax', 'Form', 'Session','Javascript','Js' => array('Jquery'));
```

and located at:

```
app/views/helpers/halp.php
```

It works fine on my local MAMP setup

(using latest clone of 1.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, it was an issue with git.

Answer (score 0):

In the view code where you are trying to use the helper, are you using $this->Halp->xxx or $Halp->xxx ?