# Issues with Deploying CakePHP Custom Helper

Tags: cakephp, deployment, cakephp-1.3, helper

I've been following a [tutorial](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/matt_1/2011/08/07/yet_another_jquery_autocomplete_helper_2) for implementing auto-complete functionality on my CakePHP 1.3 application. All of the source relevant to this approximately matches that code.

I've successfully implemented it on my local WAMP, but when deployed to my LAMP server, the app breaks (the html page only renders up to the form where the AutoCompleteHelper input function is called).

Using log statements, I see the input function fails at..

```
$options = array_replace($baseOptions,$options);
```

in the AutoCompleteHelper's input() method.  I don't seem to get any error output. Below is the output of $options:

```
Array
(
    [autoCompleteUrl] => /catalog/bands/auto_complete
    [autoCompleteRequestItem] => autoCompleteText
)
```

This doesn't look amiss to me.

Also, I found a similar, though closed, [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919319/cakephp-custom-helper-works-locally-but-not-on-server) on Stack which made me think I may have some sort of tweak outside of Cakephp to make. The more I look into this the more I think this may not be needed, but I figure it's a good point of reference.

Where do I go from here to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be difficult for anyone to troubleshoot this for you. Especially if it is working on your localhost but not another lamp environment. Chances are it's a configuration issue. Here are a few things to look into that may push you in the right direction:

- have you checked the file permissions of the files being called
- have you confirmed the file actually exists and is not missing
- have you checked the servers error log
- have you tried turning on debug in core.php to see if an error is
  being displayed on screen

Hopefully this will push you in the right direction.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the pointers, Chuck. I went to the error logs on my site and found nothing amiss, but then I realized while I was there that I had 5.2.17 on Prod versus 5.3.8 local..

And whaddya know? Array_Replace is 5.3+.. Now my problem changes towards finding a 5.2 friendly solution to resolve that or bumping up my production php version.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the issue. I know how annoying that can be, it happens to me at work all the time. ;) Happy Coding!